# What is the best session timeout for any Web Application or Website?

Tags: session, web-applications, web, session-timeout

I am wandering how long session timeout would be in any average secured website or web application ? I am currently creating my first web application. 
Any links about user session management will be welcome.

Here I am talking about web application like a simple expenses manager or a simple task manager.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *right* answer. It is context dependent. A banking site should have a much shorter session than a pizza delivery site.

I would say start at five minutes absent any analysis.

But if you can when the application is tested, figure out the average amount of time it takes to do an atomic set of common tasks (like selecting, buying, and paying for items). Then figure out the standard deviation of those values. Then maybe your session can be

```
Average + 3 Standard Deviations
```

or similar. Consider other factors like if your users are primarily old or disabled.

Also, whenever activity is detected, reset the clock regardless of whatever you choose as the session length.